# Solving an inequality as part of formal definition

Tags: limits, inequality

**The problem:**

[image: The Problem]

As part of a homework assignment, we are required to fill in the blanks in these epsilon-delta proofs of limits.

I'm having trouble solving the inequality above, which is the primary problem. How do we deal with it? I have included the main question below in as well in case that changed anything.

**Full Question:**

[image: Full Question]

Comment: 1-1/B is the answer I believe to be right, but I wanted to check it here before I submit

Comment: You should please type your question in clear as part of the main text.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. It's my first time on here and I didn't want to make a mess of it so I thought including the pictures would make it easier on the eyes in case I did.

Comment: is $$B>0$$ here?

Comment: yes i have found it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have to solve $$\frac{1}{1-x^2}>B$$ with $$B>0$$ since we have $$B>0$$ then we have $$1-x^2>0$$ and we can multiply by $$1-x^2>0$$ and we get $$1>B(1-x^2)$$ dividing by $B$ we get
$$\frac{1}{B}>1-x^2$$ from here we get
$$x^2>1-\frac{1}{B}$$ if $$B\le 1$$ then the inequality is true, else if $$B>1$$ then we have
$$|x|>\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{B}}$$ which is given in the Statement above